# How to pass an array into mssql query string?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, express

I'm using the [mssql node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) package to perform queries on a SQL Server DB.
Now I want to pass in an array of intergers to the query string. So I grab The array from req.query.rids and the values output are as follows:

```
var RIDS = JSON.parse(req.query.rids);
logger.info(`${RIDS}`)  // result shows: 204294,204303,104354
```

But when I use the `IN` operator to check for a match to any of the array values. I get the error `error: Incorrect syntax near '204294'.` What I understand from this is that the RID array being passed in is not in the correct format for the query.

**Question:**

How do I pass in an array into mssql query string?
`

This is a snippet of the query where I check for a match in the RIDS array:

```
Left Join [Metrics_DB].[dbo].[AssetBundle]
  on [Metrics_DB].[dbo].[Assetdata].RID=[Metrics_DB].[dbo].[AssetBundle].[RID]
   where [Asset Sunset Date] is not null and [OSM_Metrics_DB].[dbo].[Assetdata].RID IN ${RIDS}
```

Comment: `WHERE ... IN (value1, value2, value3, value3, ...)` - [Exploits of a mom](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stringify and format your array in the style of (item, item, item).

[Source](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php)